# How to describe this relation?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Let $\text{ann}(a;r_1,r_2)$ denote an annulus in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with center at $a$ and smaller radius $r_1$ and larger radius $r_2$, and $D_1(a,r_1)$ denotes the corresponding smaller disk. If there is another disk $D_0$ inside $D_1$, i.e. $D_0 \subset D_1$ (see [here](http://www.ras.ucalgary.ca/CGPS/products/st04/annulus.gif) for an illustration), how do I describe the relation between the disk $D_0$ and the annulus $\text{ann}(a;r_1,r_2)$? A similar relation is a disk enclosed by a circle (not its boundary). Is "enclosure" a proper name or is there any math concept or terminology exactly defined for this kind of relation? Clearly, the relation is NOT $D_0 \subset \text{ann}(a;r_1,r_2)$.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure i completely understand what you're asking for, but a totally formal way to say this is "$D_0$ is contained in the *bounded component* of $\mathbb{R}^2 - ann(a,r_1, r_2)$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know of any special term. I’d simply say that $D_0$ is a disk concentric with and surrounded by the annulus $\operatorname{ann}(a;r_1,r_2)$. One could also describe $D_0$ as a disk concentric with and disjoint from the annulus, though I suspect that most people would have to think about that one for a moment.